# NSString.length crashing after setting string to empty (@"");

Tags: ios

I've created a calculator in iOs including each number key as a separate UIButton.

I have an `NSString` called calcNumberString that holds the number being entered into the calculator. This way I can check to see if the max digit amount has been passed and prevent the user from typing anymore.

In my `viewDidLoad` event I initialize calcNumberString like so:

```
calcNumberString = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

And when I press a number key (5 for example) the following method fires:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed5 : (id) sender
{
    if(calcNumberString.length < 10)
    {
        calcNumberString = [calcNumberString stringByAppendingFormat:@"5"];
        calcLabel.text = calcNumberString;
    }
}
```

This works just fine (I can type in up to 10 digits).... until I hit the CLEAR key:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressedClear : (id) sender
{
    calcNumberString = @"";
    calcLabel.text = @"0"
}
```

It clears as expected, but when I try to press another number key after that I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` or the following `NSInvalidArgumentException`:

```
[__NSCFSet length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16c110
```

Is there something in the `buttonPressClear` method that I'm doing wrong?? It's obviously the problem as everything works fine until I clear and then try to type in new digits.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you initialize that string? You're leaking memory by reassigning its pointer.

Comment: You should really be using NSMutableString for this.

Comment: Thanks. Tried with NSMutableString, same problem.

Comment: This is a clear case of something being prematurely deallocated.  Profile this with leaks and zombies on.

Comment: Thanks. When I go to Run with Performance Tool Zombies is greyed out. How can I turn it on??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your clear button action, you are assigning calcNumberString to another memory location which you have not retain. Once that method goes out of scope, that string memory location is gone.

If you want to continue using NSString, the proper code would be the following:

```
[calcNumberString release];
calcNumberString = [@"" retain];
```

This way you don't have any memory leaks.

As @CodaFi mention in the comment, you should be using [NSMutableString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutablestring_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I thought constant strings are never deallocated, so you wouldn't need to retain?

Comment: If you use the keyword `const` but `@""` is a string [Objective-C Literals](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-06-22-objective-c-literals.html)

Comment: I meant literals... So they're not static?

Comment: In the example in the question, `calcNumberString` is a variable that will point to the memory location of where to find the string. Since its an ivar it will be around as long as the view is loaded. But when the clear method is called, and `@""` is assign to the variable, at that point in time memory is allocated. And the variable contains the address to that string. When the method is done, everything in the call stack is removed. Since we didn't issue a `retain`, that string memory is cleaned up as well.

Comment: I was talking about the @"" itself. You called [@"" retain]; I thought that was a no-op.